# Why the main does not wait until the async method has finished?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have this console application, a reduce example of my application, but that allows to reproduce the behavior.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            addAsync01(1, 2);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        addAsync01(1,2);
    }

    private static async void addAsync01(int sum1, int sum2)
    {
        int result = await AddAsync(sum1, sum2);
        Console.WriteLine("El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: " + result);
    }

    public static async Task<int> AddAsync(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return await Task<int>.Run(() =>
        {
            return num1 + num2;
        });
    }
}
```

In the `addSyn01` method,I have used a await keyword, but the application does not wait until the method `AddAsync` is finished, continue running, so the result that I get in the console is:

```
Start
Finally
El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: 3
```

I expected this:

```
Start
El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: 3
Finally
```

If I am not wrong, the `await` keyword wait that the `async` method finish to continue with the next code of line.

If I use this code in the `AddAsync01` method, it works as I expect:

```
private static async void addAsync01(int sum1, int sum2)
{
    Task<int> tskResult = AddAsync(1, 2);
    await Task.WhenAll(tskResult);

    Console.WriteLine("El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: " + tskResult.Result);
}
```

Comment: You need to `await addAsync01` as well.

Comment: Actually, you first need to redefine `addAsync01` as `Task` instead of `void`. `async void` is generally bad, except for event handlers.

Comment: `async void` methods are fire-and-forget. You get *zero* information about their progress, or their result. So it’s impossible to await them. Don’t use `async void` methods.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot you won't be able to await from `Main`

Comment: @Jonesopolis True. One of those annoying cases where you must use .Wait/Result as the answer below suggests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Console applications do not support `async / await` on the entry point of the application, as you might expect them to.  You need to invoke `.Wait()` or (`.Result` for `Task<T>` returning methods).  I would suggest looking into [Stephen Cleary's Async Console Program](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) if you're curious about why it doesn't work as you'd expect.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");

            addAsync01(1, 2).Wait();
        }
        catch
        {
            //TODO
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        addAsync01(1, 2).Wait();
    }

    static async Task addAsync01(int sum1, int sum2)
    {
        int result = await AddAsync(sum1, sum2);
        Console.WriteLine("El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: " + result);
    }

    public static async Task<int> AddAsync(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => num1 + num2);
    }
}
```

Additionally, you need to return `Task` on the `addAsync01` method.

Here is the output with the changes:

```
Start
El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: 3
Finally
```

While this change does work and correctly answers your question, it is odd to me that you would want to introduce asynchronous code without an obvious reason.  If you're simply trying to understand how it functions, fine; however if this is desirable code you might want to reconsider the approach.  The summation of two `int's` is not computationally expensive at all, and this could be done synchronously much faster and with less overhead.

Comment: Thanks David. Really is for  testing, because the real method is not a sum, is a method that use async methods from entity framework. Really I have used the await with async EF methods and works as I expected, but in this case not and I wanted to know the reason. In my real application it's a library project, not a console application.

Comment: Happy I could help!  In your class library you should use async / await.  The async keyword lets the method use the await keyword, and the await keyword will basically suspend the method invocation and return once the asynchronously method yields its result (or returns from execution).  This is the ideal way to handle Task and Task<T>.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the addAsync01() method to be synchronous, don't declare it as async. When not declaring the method as async, you won't be able to use "await" inside it. So you must explicitely wait for the asynchronous method called from the synchronous method the following way:

```
    private static void addAsync01(int sum1, int sum2)
    {
        var lTask = AddAsync(sum1, sum2);
        lTask.Wait();
        int result = lTask.Result;

        Console.WriteLine("El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: " + result);
    }
```

Be careful when using such code inside complexer multi-threading environments. It is very easy to produce deadlocks.